# Iterating XML with lxml in Python: how to know how much of the input file has been read?

Tags: python, xml, lxml

I'm using `lxml.etree.iterparse()` to iterate through a large XML file.

I would like to know how far I've got in the parsing of the input file, so that I might get a progress indicator.

My first idea was to use `os.stat( filename ).st_size` to know how big is my XML file, then as I'm getting events from the parser, retrieve the current position in the file. But I can't figure out how `lxml.etree` could give me access to its internal position. `iterparse()` is taking a filename as its `source` argument, so I can't open myself the file and call its `tell()` method to known how many bytes have been read so far.

Are you aware of any `lxml.etree` built-in indicator for current parser progression ? Or do you have an idea of integrating such a progression ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could pass a file object to `iterparse`, and then call `f.tell()`.
This will give you the approximate position of the Element in the file.

```
import lxml.etree as ET
import os

filename = 'data.xml'
total_size = os.path.getsize(filename)
with open(filename, 'r') as f:
    context = ET.iterparse(f, events=('end', ), tag='Record')
    for event, elem in context:
        print(event, elem, float(f.tell())/total_size)
```

will yield something like

```
(u'end', <Element Record at 0xb743e2d4>, 0.09652665470688218)
(u'end', <Element Record at 0xb743e2fc>, 0.09652665470688218)
(u'end', <Element Record at 0xb743e324>, 0.09652665470688218)
...
(u'end', <Element Record at 0xb744739c>, 1.0)
(u'end', <Element Record at 0xb74473c4>, 1.0)
(u'end', <Element Record at 0xb74473ec>, 1.0)
```

Comment: Oh nice ! The documentation does not specify the type of the `source` argument, and the examples only make use of a filename.

Answer (score 0):

You should not use

```
with open(filename, 'r') as f:
```

because it will result in memory error in bigger files. it is better to traverse the file and just count the rows so you can guess how much of the file is left.

Comment: It may be a good hint to use chunk size with cursor.itersize like [here](https://medium.com/@rizwanbutt314/efficient-way-to-read-large-postgresql-table-with-python-934d3edfdcc).